# In quiver is it possible to see what all objects used and where they are referenced

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is there a way to see what all objects are used in quiver in a JSON format or any other way? However I can see objects under analysis content.

But here is the problem, there are some objects that are deleted now and quiver is still referencing those objects which are not showing up under analysis content. How I can see where are these object references are made in quiver so that I can remove those references.

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed items from the canvas, check the Analysis Contents section from the left-hand nav as seen in [the lower left of this part of the documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/analysis-canvas/#moving-and-resizing-cards-on-the-canvas) where it shows "not in canvas". From there you could [check the graph view](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/analysis-graph/) to see where those nodes fit into the analysis...